# Do gentiles have Gilgul Neshamot?

Tags: reincarnation

I have not heard a concrete answer (or even a generalized opinion) on whether gentiles can have a re-incarnation, despite reading that they do not (Minchas Yehuda by Rabbi Yehuda Hachayat). I know that there are sources that say that a gentile does not have as many layers of soul as a Jew, and also that a righteous gentile has a place in the world to come, but other than that nothing definitive.

I have emailed the Chabad "Ask the Rabbi" service and was told, in essence, that it is complicated and not to delve into it, which was not a satisfying answer to me.

The reason I am asking is because I enjoy learning from video lectures and many of the Rabbis and speakers I enjoy listening to tend to speak to both gentile and Jewish audiences , and they sometimes mention re-incarnation passively in the context of life circumstances, suffering etc. It's because they have both a gentile and Jewish audience that I ask, because I have seen cursory mentions in some places that gentiles sort of only have one go.

Comment: This might help you: https://hakirah.org/Vol%2016%20Balk.pdf

Comment: This is a very comprehensive document but it does not at all address any part of my question. Thank you though.

Comment: This topic is discussed at some length in this book: https://menuchapublishers.com/products/ive-been-here-before

Comment: No offense, but theres really no way to verify this, and honestly i have a hard time believing this sort of thing. Do you have any actual Jewish sources with roots in theology instead of a for-profit book?

Comment: Okay! Have you studied Tanya by the Alter Rebbe?

Comment: I haven't, does it clarify my question? I'm really just looking for a yes or no or "in xyz case yes/no" kind of answer,

Comment: Well, I personally would suggest you read it, but that's completely up to you ofcourse. As the Rabbi from the Ask the Rabbi-service stated, it is really complicated.

Comment: Sure, but can you advise some sections or passages that would help me out rather than search through the whole thing? What I know of the Tanya is kind of disparriaging toward gentiles, saying their souls eminate from unclean places/evil realms etc. I would presume that this would be a no to Gilgul but then again I'm jut speculating.

Comment: This must have come up a handful of times in diff sources I read, but I cant remember where or what. My memory man.. I wont use the same disclaimer as u did end of ur post, bc hopefully its not a disability, maybe just so much stress in life or something the last.. 2 decades+.. lol..that its discarding non-survival info, but heres what little I remember, hopefully someone will have fuller answer. There are famous examples of evil ppl in Tanach that had reincarnations who were gentiles, like Nimrod. So maybe that means they can reincarnate.

Comment: But the details & differences for each group would be nice to remember. Also I wonder what happens when a non-Jew reincarnates into a Jew, is that considered an example that non-Jews can reincarnate?

Like what about Esau. He was born to Isaac, and circumcised. So Jewish. Rejected his birthright, so became an Edomite. Then he reincarnates into a Jew, and this Jew becomes another religion. So in both cases, starts off Jewish, ends non-Jewish. Therefore, is this reincarnation of Esau considered evidence that non-Jews can reincarnate, or not? But the Nimrod example might be more clear cut

Comment: Correction, some sources say Esau was circumcised, but some say he was not. I either saw or remembered that for the first time after checking after writing my comment. It wasn't the focus of my post or I would have checked first. Sorry.

Comment: IDK what your reasoning is but usually if someone comes from the patriarchs I would call them Jewish. also, in regards to your statement: "There are famous examples of evil ppl in Tanach that had reincarnations who were gentiles" its well known that its possible for a jew to come back as a gentile - they still have a Jewish soul, my question is regarding just plain gentiles, with gentile souls, the question I am asking is do they re-incarnate?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! I fixed a few typos and removed your last sentence, in general there is no need to worry about typos. Many others make them as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a tough time typing sometimes and I ws worried I might not get taken seriously if there were errors.

Comment: You can try to contact a Rabbi via this website: https://kabbalah.com/en/contact/ they are specialized in Kabbalah.

Comment: thank you! I have emailed them. I hope they respond.

Comment: They finally responded, they told me to buy a 20 class course about the soul to get an answer. So I guess I'll never know.